# UITextField not becoming first responder in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in one of my collection view cells. I want it to become first responder as soon as that cell is on screen.

So, I call `[cell.textField becomeFirstResponder]` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. However, this only works when the app is opened (the cell containing the uitextfield is already visible on app launch), if I scroll away from the cell and than scroll back to it, the textfield does not become first responder anymore.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:** I am programatically scrolling the collection view to the cell containing the `UITextField` before calling `becomeFirstResponder`

Comment: Can you post your code where you scroll to the specific cell?

Comment: I solved it by a slightly different approach, check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as the scrolling of the collection view made the collection view the first responder until the scrolling finished, so I made my textfield the first responder in this delegate method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in the

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

function as according to the [class ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:):

> Tells the delegate that the specified cell is about to be displayed in the collection view.

Comment: Thanks, will definetly try it tonight! Until then, can you tell me why would this work if cellForItemAtIndexPath doesn't work?

Comment: It seems as though this function is called right before the cell is about to be drawn, not just when it is initially drawn so it should work.

Comment: Also, note that your answer is for UITableView, I am using UICollectionView. However, there is similar method since iOS 8: - `(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Ah my bad there, will change it right now. They have the same methods as you said, so it's the same idea.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately this does not work either I edited my answer to provide some more information!